# soapUI - Oauth2 and Basic Authentication to retrieve token

Tags: oauth-2.0, soapui, basic-authentication

I need to develop a SoapUi test using to oauth2, the authorization API requires Basic Authentication.

I tried to use the *[username]:[password]@url* approch, but the password contains a special character @ that gets changed to %40, I also changed the Enconding but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I added the header in the class EnabledWebViewBasedBrowserComponent

```
public void navigate(final String url, String errorPage) {
    if (SoapUI.isBrowserDisabled()) {
        return;
    }
    setErrorPage(errorPage);

    this.url = url;

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getWebEngine().setUserAgent("\nAuthorization: Basic bWNb25lhbGRzlk1jRDuGxklWg==");
            getWebEngine().load(url);
        }
    });
}
```